# aws s3 command responds with 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Trying to install AWS CodeDeploy agent on my EC2 instance

```
aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2/latest/install . --region ap-southeast-2
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

The IAM Role for the instance has Policy Document

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and Trust relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codedeploy.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does `aws s3 ls s3://aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2 --region ap-southeast-2` work?

Comment: `wget https://aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install` worked.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

That command is not correct. `cp`is used to upload something to S3, to download a file you could use `curl` or `wget`:

```
curl -O https://aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
```

or

```
wget https://aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
```

Comment: `aws s3 cp` can both download and upload, depending on which argument (bucket or local) is first.  The command is used this way in the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/resource-kit.html

Answer (score 1):

I followed the guideline at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux.html

Also I attached AdministratorGroup Policy to my user.

Code Deploy agent is now running in my box.